# Why do I get unreferenced local variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Is it a compiler bug (I'm using Visual C++12 from VS2013) or I don't understand something?
But I got warning C4101: 'a' : unreferenced local variable on this code

```
class A
{
public:
    static int i;
};
int A::i;

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.i = 9;
}
```

Comment: Probably because `a` is not really needed for anything.

Comment: Indeed, you could just as easily do `A::i = 9;`.

Comment: You can do:  `A a = A();` This will get rid of it for sure.

Comment: No warnings with g++ and `-Wall`.

Comment: It is still warning with std::cout << a.i;

Comment: @Dmitry I think this may be because `i` is static. You really don't need an instance to manipulate it, that's probably what the compiler is ranting about.

Comment: No issues [here](http://ideone.com/2ax2HM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is static, which means it belongs to the class, not the instance. You should actually write `A::i = 9`. When you consider that, you should see that the variable `a` is actually never being used.

Comment: But what about something like this

    'A a;
    a.i = 9;
    int y = rand();
    while (y--)
        a.i++;'

Comment: That will have no difference, because `i` will still be static. Each time you write `a.i` (using the instance, the variable `a`,) the compiler is converting it to `A::i` for you (using the class.) It sounds like you did not intend to make `i` a static variable.

Answer (score 2):

You've made `i` static which means there's only one global copy. Try accessing it with `A::i`. Note that the above code (OP's) works with gcc.

`i` isn't actually 'owned' by the instantiation `a` but rather the class `A`.

Comment: `a` is not static. `A::i` is.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that as soon as I hit post. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Because `i` is `static`, the code

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.i = 9;
}
```

is automatically replaced with

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    A::i = 9;
}
```

Now it's obvious why `a` is unreferenced.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees that after defining variable a it was not assigned a value and it itself was not assigned to other object.